# Revert cppyy automatic mapping of operator() to __getitem__ via C++ pythonization callback

Tags: python, cppyy

As is also explained in [this cppyy issue](https://bitbucket.org/wlav/cppyy/issues/262/over), an `A& operator()` on the C++ side is mapped to the python `__getitem__`.

On the issue it is suggested to add a special pythonization if this is not the wished for result.

An extra constraint in my case would be to add this to the C++ class itself to ensure that this pythonization is always applied.

I'm however having trouble figuring out how to properly do this via the Python C API. (1st time working with the that API so I'm a bit lost)

Minimal Reproducer somewhat contrived but shows the problem:
**Note** in the example below that `struct A` is code that I can't modify because that class is defined in library code. So the callback has to be in B.

```py
import cppyy


cppyy.include("Python.h")

cppyy.cppdef(r"""

void myprint(PyObject* py){
    PyObject* tmp = PyObject_Str(py);
    Py_ssize_t size = 0;
    const char* s = PyUnicode_AsUTF8AndSize(tmp, &size);
    std::cout << std::string(s, size) << std::endl;
}

template <typename T>
struct A {
  T& operator[](size_t idx) { return arr[idx]; }
  const T& operator[](size_t idx) const { return arr[idx]; }
  std::array<T, 10> arr{};
};

template <typename T>
struct B : public A<T> {
  B& operator()() { return *this; };

  static void __cppyy_pythonize__( PyObject* klass, const std::string& name){
    std::cout << "Hello from pythonize" << std::endl;

    PyObject* getitem = PyObject_GetAttrString(klass, "__getitem__");

    myprint(getitem);
  }
};


using tmp = B<double>;
""")


t = cppyy.gbl.B['double']
print(t.__getitem__.__doc__)
```

I can get the `__getitem__` function from the `PyObject* klass` but, as explained in the docs, the callback happens at the very end after all the internal processing of the class.
Thus the `__call__` function, which here is `B& operator()()`,  has already been mapped to `__getitem__`.

Unfortunately, I can't for the life of me figure out how I would undo that mapping and get back that old `__getitem__` function.
Is that `operator[]()` function even still accessible via the `PyObject* klass` ?

Any help/pointers would be much appreciated :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, to answer your question, to find the `__getitem__` you want, get it from the base class of `klass`, not from `klass` directly. You can also do this in Python, rather than adding pythonizations in C++. In fact, doing this in Python is preferred as then you don't have to deal with the C-API.

However, since the actual bug report is not the one you referenced, but [this one](https://github.com/root-project/root/issues/7179), and since the suggestion made there, which you followed here, makes this a classic XY-problem, let me also add that what you really want is to simply do `PyObject_DelAttrString(klass, "__getitem__")` in your code example.

Completely aside, the code that is giving you trouble here is from the Gaudi project, the core developers of which are the ones who asked for this automatic mapping in the first place. You may want to take this up with them.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the quick reply Wim!   
The reason I wanted to do this in the C-API is that I didn't see a way to do it globally with the Python one.   
Also, in the end it doesn't seem like a complicated solution!
Just feel that I've now got even more questions as it's not obvious to me why that works :D 
In any case thanks again for taking the time to reply and solve my problem :)